# Finding a struct in a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I want to find a struct whose ***all*** member data match certain values.

I made a following short program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct vlan {
    int vlanId;
    bool status;
};

vector<vlan> vlanTable; 

int main(){
    vlan tmp;
    tmp.status = true;
    tmp.vlanId = 1;
    vector <vlan>::iterator flag = find(vlanTable.begin(), vlanTable.end(), tmp);
    if ( flag != vlanTable.end()){
        cout<<"found"<<endl;
    }
    else cout<<"not found"<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It returns error as: template argument deduction/substitution failed right at the find function.

Could someone help me?

Comment: 1. You need in `#include <algorithm>` 2. your struct needs an `operator==` to know how to compare for equality

Comment: @Ripi2: I tried to fill up the vlanTable in main, but see that the same error still occurs. In fact, I think I should be able to search in an empty vlanTable. If found item , don't do sth, if not found, push an item into the vector vlanTable. Therefore, vlanTable could be empty at first.

Comment: @UnholySheep: Could you please elaborate ? I don't quite understand. Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at your error message again -- I suspect that "template argument deduction/substitution failed" is not the _complete_ message.  There should be more.  Probably some mention of an "operator ==".

Comment: If you're using visual studio, The `error` pane only contains error _summaries_, and the full error message is in the `output` pane.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to provide the `==` operator for your `vlan` class:

```cpp
struct vlan {
    int vlanId;
    bool status;
    bool operator==(const vlan& rhs) const {
        return (vlanId == rhs.vlanId) && (status == rhs.status);
    }
};
```

Also, as noted in the comments, you should `#include <algorithm>` (for the definition of `std::find`); some compilers *may* implicitly include this from other headers, but don't rely on that.

---

Note that, as per the comment made by [aschepler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/459640/aschepler), if you have a compiler that conforms to the C++20 (or later) Standard, you can define the `operator==` for your `vlan` class as defaulted:

```cpp
struct vlan {
    int vlanId;
    bool status;
    bool operator==(const vlan& rhs) const = default; // C++20
};
```

For your `vlan` struct, this will perform the exact same comparison(s) as the 'explicit' version defined above. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_comparisons) (or the [Draft C++20 Standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.eq) itself):

> ###### Defaulted equality comparison
>
> A class can define `operator==` as defaulted, with a return value
> of `bool`. This will generate an equality comparison of each base
> class and member subobject, in their declaration order. Two objects are
> equal if the values of their base classes and members are equal. The
> test will short-circuit if an inequality is found in members or base
> classes earlier in declaration order.

Comment: this is awesome! I was struggling for a day and you solve it after 3 minutes I posted the question. 

But could you explain further why this operator overloading of == resolves the issues ? In other words, why did the compiler shows error: template argument deduction/substitution failed and this operator overloading helps ?

Comment: @MinhPham If you don't provide the `==` operator, then the `std::find` algorithm doesn't 'know' how to compare 2 `vlan` objects. Built-in types have pre-defined comparisons; classes and structs that you define don't have those.

Comment: @MinhPham C++ does not know what makes your structs "equal" -- only you know that.  You have two member variables, `vLanId` and `status`.  If C++ were to decide by itself with no help as to what makes your structs equal, maybe it would have used only one of those members and compared them.   So C++ steps out the way and cannot decide on its own what makes them equal.  Thus you have to write the code to tell C++ what makes the structs equal, and that is why you need to overload `==`.

Comment: @MinhPham -- Note that C++ 20 does have a spaceship operator `<=>` that does do what you want, automatically.

Comment: Or, if using a C++20 mode, you can shorten the above to `bool operator==(const vlan& rhs) const = default;`. (Defining a spaceship operator will also define `operator!=`, `operator<`, `operator>`, `operator<=`, `operator>=`, which you might or might not want.)

Comment: @aschepler Excellent observation. Would you object if I incorporated that into my answer? (I don't want to unilaterally "Steal your thunder!")

Comment: @AdrianMole No problem. (All SE questions, answers, and comments are CC BY-SA 4.0, and I'd seldom make a fuss if the attribution was missing.)

Answer (score 5):

In C++, structs do not have a comparison operator generated by default. You need to write your own:

```
struct vlan {
    int vlanId;
    bool status;

    bool operator==(const vlan& v) const
    {
        return vlanId == v.vlanId; // or another approach as above
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use std::find_if with a lambda you can tune for a specific query.
Or you if you only need to search by id quickly then you can also use a map.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

struct vlan 
{
    size_t vlanId = 0 ;      
    bool status = false;
};

std::vector<vlan> vlanTable;
std::map<size_t, vlan> vlanMap;

bool findInTable(const size_t id)
{
    auto it = std::find_if(vlanTable.begin(), vlanTable.end(), [id](const auto& item) 
    { 
        return item.vlanId == id; // add more checks here
    });

    return (it != vlanTable.end());
}


int main() 
{
    vlan tmp1{ 1,true };

    vlanTable.push_back(tmp1);
    auto found_in_table = findInTable(1);

    vlanMap.insert({ tmp1.vlanId,tmp1 });
    auto found_in_map = (vlanMap.find(1) != vlanMap.end());

    std::cout << "ID 1 ";
    if (!found_in_table) std::cout << "not ";
    std::cout << "found in table" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "ID 1 ";
    if (!found_in_map) std::cout << "not ";
    std::cout << "found in map" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you ! I tried it and sees that it works